# DataRequired validator detect blank spaces but don't show error message

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am working on a flask application where I have a WTForm with required fields. I used DataValidator to make sure fields are not empty. It does display an error message when the field is empty but doesn't display the error message when only blank spaces are entered, but it doesn't validate the form either, I just end up being redirected to the same page until I enter some valid input. I thought it was a bug on my project but I created a new project and the same thing happened. Is that a normal behaviour of the validator or is it a bug on wtform.
Here is a snippet of the wtform.

```
class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):
    """Class for adding a form to template"""

    first_name = StringField("first name ", validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField(
        "Last Name",
        validators=[DataRequired()],
    )
    desc = StringField(
        "Description",
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        widget=TextArea(),
    )
    age = IntegerField(
        "Age",
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            NumberRange(min=1, message="Age must be at least 1"),
        ],
        default=1,
    )
    tag_1 = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    tag_2 = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Save")
```

Here is a snippet of the view.py code :

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from .form_models import AddUserForm
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = SECRET_KEY


@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_faq():
    
    form = AddUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.data.items())

    return render_template("add_user.html", form=form)
```

And a snippet of the template

```
<form style="padding-bottom: 50px;" action="" method="POST" role="form" class="form" autocomplete="off">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

                {{ wtf.form_field(form.first_name) }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.last_name , placeholder='Last name') }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.age , placeholder='age') }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.desc ,
                placeholder='Description of user', rows='20') }}

                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="form-control-label">Tags:</label>

                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Tag 1" required type="text" style="margin-bottom:5px;"
                        id="tag_1" name="tag_1" {% if form.tag_1.data is not none %} value="{{ form.tag_1.data }}" {%
                        endif %}>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Tag 2" required type="text" style="margin-bottom:5px;"
                        id="tag_2" name="tag_2" {% if form.tag_2.data is not none %} value="{{ form.tag_2.data }}" {%
                        endif %}>

                    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="total_tags">
                    <div id="new_tags"></div>

                    <input class="btn btn-secondary add" type="button" value="+ Tag"
                        style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <input class="btn btn-secondary remove" type="button" value="- Tag"
                        style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
                </div>

                {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
```

I tried using InputValidator but it doesn't check for blank spaces. I also tried adding a custom message to the DataValidator. Again it worked when the field is empty but doesn't send the message when the field is not empty.

Flask 2.1.1 Flask-WT 1.0.0 WTForms 3.0.0

Comment: Can you please give us a reproducible code example?

Comment: Please show us your template code. The `DataRequired` validator should also react to whitespace and deliver an error message, which can be accessed in the template under the respective input field. For example, you can iterate over `form.first_name.errors' and display the messages associated with that field.

Comment: I added the template code. I tried displaying the errors and it worked. But it doesn't display the message associated with the field under the field. In fact in doesn't show any error at all. But it does show errors when the field is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validators to solve your problem. Add a method to your class that test for the validity of your field.

here is your code:

```
class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):
    """Class for adding a form to template"""

    first_name = StringField("first name ", validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField(
        "Last Name",
        validators=[DataRequired()],
    )

    ...

    submit = SubmitField("Save")

    def validate_first_name(form, field):
        if not field.strip():
            raise ValidationError('This Field is required')
```

You can as well strip the string before submitting the form.

I hope this helped.